# Search box will not close when I click outside of it

Tags: jquery

i have an problem with my dropdown search menu
the searchbox wil simpley not close when i click outside of it

here is my javascript

```
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function()
{
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#result").html(html).show();
        }
        });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#searchid').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
        jQuery("#result").fadeOut();
        }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
```

PHP script

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST)
{
$q=$_POST['search'];
$sql_res=mysql_query("select playid,name,link,image from channels where name like '%$q%' or playid like '%$q%' order by playid LIMIT 8");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
{
$title=$row['name'];
$itemid=$row['playid'];
$image=$row['image'];
$b_title='<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$final_title = str_ireplace($q, $b_title, $title);
?>
<div class="show" align="left">
<a href="../player.php?playid=<?php echo $itemid; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" /><span class="name"><?php echo $title; ?></span>&nbsp;<br/><br/>
</a>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

And the script where in showing the input box

```
    <div class="content navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="search form-control" id="searchid" placeholder="Search..." /><br /> 
        <div id="result">
        </div>
        </div>
```

i simpley dont have any ide about how i fix this.

Here is an image of it
http://billedeupload.dk/images/mVpa.png
cant post images yet sorry, but there is the link to it ^

it works fine in jsfiddle? :-/
http://jsfiddle.net/3r8ovqgg/

i got this error in chrome Scarch line 21

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);
});
```

Any ides?

Comment: It might be useful if you created a jsFiddle to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Yah, but i cant use PHP on JS fiddle :-/

Comment: That's true ... but I am supposing that your PHP is building a stream of HTML that is sent to the browser and that HTML is not acting as you want.  If you thus create a jsFiddle of the HTML that is sent by your server side code, the same symptom should be present without PHP involvement.

Comment: hmm i tryed, but i ditten seem to work, cause the javascript is getting infomation from url: "search.php",

Comment: here is an link http://jsfiddle.net/3r8ovqgg/ but in jsfiddle it works? it close the box when you click outside of it :-/

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using both `$` and `jQuery` notation for jQuery objects? Also, all the `jQuery()` objects are outside of the DOM ready function.

Comment: so if i should rewrite, how would i do that :)?, im pretty new in java :)

Comment: I would guess `$("<div/>")` returns an empty list. To select a tag, just write the tag name without <> and slashes. As per HTML definition a tag name followed by a slash <div/> is an empty tag. Your code shows only starting tags <div> and closing tags </div>. Does a selection without slash $("div") help?

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? `live` was remove in v1.9 ps, please dont refer to javascript as java, they are absolutely not the same thing

Comment: i fixed it, i have includede 2 different jQuery -.- thanks to all for thery time! <3

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, i have includede 2 different jQuery -.- thanks to all for thery time! <3